# Use app script to insert more than one row into a sheet on button click

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a code written to insert a single row into a google sheet below a keyword (a little clunky but I don't mind, unless anyone has a fix for it off the top of their head). Problem is, I want to add 250 rows beneath that and, being new to app scripts, I'm not sure where to specify the number of rows I want it adding for me.

Here's what the code I've got looks like:

```
function addRows() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var EditSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing"); //source sheet

  var LastRowEdit = ss.getLastRow();

  for(var i = 1; i <= LastRowEdit; i++)
  {

    if(EditSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == 'add') //keyword
    {
 
      EditSheet.insertRowAfter(i);
    
    }

  }

}
```

I would love to hear your suggestions for how I can adjust this to match my goals.

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany)` instead of `insertRowAfter(afterPosition)`? So, how about the following modifcation?

#### From:

```
EditSheet.insertRowAfter(i);
```

#### To:

```
EditSheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 250);
```

By the way, in your script, `getValue()` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. In order to reduce the cost, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function addRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var EditSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing");
  var LastRowEdit = ss.getLastRow();
  var row = EditSheet.getRange("A1:A" + LastRowEdit).getValues().map(([a]) => a).indexOf("add");
  if (row != -1) {
    EditSheet.insertRowsAfter(row + 1, 250);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany)

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thank you so much; I really appreciate your help. :D

Comment: @Mae Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.